# Jquery csspie pie.js does not work in IE8?

Tags: jquery

Trying to get IE8 to work with csspie and its pie.js file.
Does not seem to work that well.

```
if (window.PIE) {
    $('.jspDrag').each(function() { PIE.attach(this); });
}
```

It doesn't even start the loop. Making me crazy.

Comment: Get this error in chrome...what? I target IE on this one.

     Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'attachEvent'

Comment: Check your debugger and see of the PIE file is in the correct path and is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is here about pie.js : http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

I just test it into a project, and it works very well.

An exemple :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/pathToPie/PIE.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
    if (window.PIE) {
      $('.myClassToAttach').each(function() {
       PIE.attach(this);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```